# Update specific record inside jsonb column containing multiple objects

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, jsonb

**Consider the column named "DocumentInformation" of type **jsonb** having this specific record:**

```html
[
 {
    "SchoolsCode": 22,
    "SchoolsName": "Home School",
  },
  {
    "SchoolsCode": "101770",
    "SchoolsName": "Blossom Senior High School",
  }
]
```

**Here's the postgresql query I was trying with, to update the value of schoolCode on the basis of SchoolName.**

```html
Update SchoolRecords set DocumentInformation = jsonb_set(documentInformation, '{schoolCode}', '"00001"') where documentInformation ->> 'SchoolName' = 'Home School'
```

**But getting the fail response as:**

```html
UPDATE 0

Query returned successfully in 401 msec.
```

Comment: Is SchoolCode a primary key?  Update only works when value is already in database.  So use Insert instead of Update.

Comment: Please go through the Query once, you will understand. What i am actually trying to do.

Comment: I understand what you are doing.  You cannot update a value that is not in the database when you have a primary key!!!

Comment: Ok let's suppose if SchoolCode has some value, then how we are gonna update it?

Comment: Update will work if key is in database.  Issue is when a new value is being put into database UPDATE will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the index of the arrays to be modified and then modify it with jsonb_set like that:

```
with my_json as (
select ('{'||index-1||',SchoolsCode}')::text[] as path
from school_records,
jsonb_array_elements(document_information) with ordinality arr(di,index)
 where di->> 'SchoolsName'='Home School'
)
update school_records set document_information = jsonb_set(document_information,my_json.path,'"000001"')
from my_json;
```

[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bdispLYet1E5Nq465wNwrC/0)

Comment: Is there any way to update the value for multiple keys, I mean Suppose one extra field **Country** is added in the JSONB column, now I want the value of **SchoolsCode** also get updated and **Country** also gets updated for the same index if condition satisfies.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think that you have to make 2 queries. jsonb_set accepts only one field at a time.